# Disbale nouveau driver in Centos 8

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, centos

I have **windows 10** preinstalled in my **msi ge62 apache** laptop. I am trying to dual boot it with **CentOS 8 workstation**.
The problems I face are:
**1.** I have to go and install centos in basic graphic mode from the troubleshooting menu. As i cannot directly install it as it hangs on black screen.
**2.** I am able to install it in basic graphic mode and I tried to disable **nouveau** driver and install **nvidia** driver as explained [here](https://linuxconfig.org/redhat-8-nvidia-driver-install-guide) and [here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_8&p=nvidia) but I face the same problem, it hangs while booting.
I have figured out that there is not just one **gpu** as the commands, `lshw` and `lspci` suggest.
Here is the a part of the output of `lshw -short`.
`/0/100/1/0    display    GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] 
/0/100/2       display    HD Graphics 530`
Does it mean I have to disable **nouveau** and install **intel** drivers instead of **nvidia** and then **nvidia**?